# NUnit: OneTimeSetUp not being recognized

Tags: c#, nunit

I just started having this issue today after updating my nuget packages, specifically the NUnit package to 3.9.1. I have always decorated my selenium test files as unit tests through NUnit and have utilized the various different tags to specify the different "parts" of each test fixture.

I use the OneTimeSetUp tag on each fixture to launch my browser and sign into the web app. I use the OneTimeTearDown tag to dispose of my driver and close the browser. I use the Test tag to specify the tests themselves, and I also have a Retry tag that I use on each test to retry based on outcome.

After updating to 3.9.1, it seems as if the OneTimeSetUp and OneTimeTearDown, along with the Retry tags are no longer recognized by visual studio, however the Test tags all are recognized.

[image: example]

Does anyone have any ideas as to why these attributes are no longer being recognized after working over the past few months? Any direction would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no v3.9.1 of NUnit - do you mean 3.9?

Comment: What version of NUnit did you upgrade from? OneTimeSetup and Retry are still in NUnit 3.9.0, so there is something wrong with your update. Also, what framework are your tests targeting, .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out on the update, for some reason it downloaded the dll of NUnit v2.6, and I'm assuming that both OneTimeSetUp and OneTimeTearDown were not present in NUnit 2.6 and my system was reading that dll instead of the new one.

I deleted NUnit 2.6 from my project and it instantly was able to recognize the other tags.